# Xbox One Controller in Java without externel libary

Tags: java, swing, controller, xbox

Me and my mates have to programm a game at university. The Problem is that we are not allowed to use external libaries such as JInput. 
Is there any possibilty to do this just with Swing or other integrated Java libaries?

Comment: Side note: Ask if you're allowed to use JavaFX instead of Swing, as Swing is now in maintenance mode and JavaFX is the designated successor.

Comment: @Puce  *"Swing is now in maintenance mode .."*  I occasionally hear that, and always ask:  What's your (Oracle based) reference on that?  So far I've yet to get one.

Comment: Not unless you're prepared to start writing a lot of low level C/C++ code and create the DLL's you'd need to provide a native interface for Java to talk with

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the reference at hand. The closest thing I currently have is: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6